# How to logout from wordpress without using wp-login.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, logout

We completely disabled the wp-login.php for security reasons.

But we would like to allow users to log out, but this requires the `wp-login.php`

So how could we write our own logout page that does not involve using `wp-login.php` ?

Comment: Explain `"totally disabled"` - eg deleted the file / blocked access via webserver etc

Comment: Blocked in htacces.
Try it forexample: http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/wp-login.php

Comment: Ok, then just call `wp_logout();` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a page - like `wp-logout.php` - that runs `session_destroy()` 
 or better yet, `wp_logout()` ([wp manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout))

Albeit, I should offer an alternative to completely disabling that...

You could, for example, have a whitelist of IP's - and in your `wp-login.php` have:

```
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], explode("\n",file_get_contents('whitelist.lst'))){
 header("Location: http://yourpage.com"); exit(); 
}
```

Alternatively, you could just store the whitelist in an array that comes right before that...

`$whitelist = array("123.456.789.100", "98.87.65.54"); //etc`

Comment: I have white list in htaccess,but I don't trust any user on my site...(I have good reasens).
Wp-logout.php is missing
I just saw lot of video, where use the wp-login.php for a atack, and then I just decided for completly disabled this.

Comment: what kind of attack? Brute force?

Comment: Not exactly. this just a half part of true
I think about this forexample:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be7VsTIRurA

Comment: Oh no, not brute force at all! Interesting! You should try that on your own wordpress. That has very likely been patched since then, but given this exploit requires a particular plugin, The odds are that it *never* worked on your WP.

Comment: Well I think is after I disabled the wp-login.php this method is not possible.
Plugins:
I don't know what useing it, but I'm pretty sure is a 403 close enough for anything right?

Comment: Yeah ~ I mean, I have something very similar implemented on my company's server, so. Good enough. I personally also have requests for `?author=1` blocked, since the admin username may be enumerated that way.

Comment: Can you edit my question for I no get any vote down?
I mean this is ridiculous.
The question I think is a good question, becouse not have answer for...
And I litlle missunderstanded your answer, so I searched the wp-logout.php which not exited yet, but now exist :D
Can you add in brackets to must be do one?